# How do I create smoother movement in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using the Python Crash Course Book by Eric Matthes and there is a project where I am currently coding a game that's basically space invaders. However, the movement of my ship is very  rough, since I'm just updating the position by adding/subtracting values to its rect each time I press an arrow key. How do I make it so the ship moves smoothly?

Here is the code for the arrow presses in a file titled game functions:

```
import sys
import pygame

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to key releases."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False


def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)
            

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()
    
    # Make sure the most recently drawn screen is visible
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This is the code for the ship and its movements:

```
import pygame

class Ship():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/spaceship.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # Start new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # Store a decimal value for the ship's center
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

        # Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's position based on the movement flag."""
        # Update the ship's center value not the rect.
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        # Update rect object from self.center.
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

And here is the code to run the game:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf



def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Make a ship
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)
run_game()
```

How do I make the movement of the ship smooth?

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth" exactly? Do you mean acceleration? Or is it like the game is lagging?

Comment: I just wanted to know if I could make the movement continuous if you know what I mean. Every time I press the right or left arrow, the ship just moves 30 pixels right, and if I reduce the amount it increases by, the ship moves way too slow.

Comment: In your code it seems like you should be able to make the ship move continuously by holding down the right or left key, and making it stop by releasing the keys. If that's not the case, then you seem to have a bug somewhere in your code. Does the ship only move once when you press the right or left button?

Comment: It works as expected but the motion is just jerky since the ship essentially teleports to the right or left 5 pixels making it look unsmooth.

Comment: But that's how animation works; it'll teleport x amount of pixels each frame. There is something else that's wrong. To me, it sounds like the framerate is bad, or that the ship is only moving once when you press the right or left button (i.e. not continuously). You should probably provide a video to show the issue.

Comment: If this makes it easier to understand, the problem is my ship moves way too slowly when I make ship.speed_factor 1 or a small number.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But you're updating the ship's position every frame. Let's assume you run at 30 FPS. Updating the position by 1 will make the ship move 1 pixel every frame or 30 pixels per second. Updating the position by 5 will make the ship move 5 pixels every frame or 150 pixels per second. There is now way for the ship to move 1 pixel each frame and be faster than 30 pixels per second. Which is why I don't understand what you mean. To me it seems like either: 1. The ship **doesn't** move each frame, 2. The game lags, 3. There is a bug that messes up time or the ship's position.

Comment: Do you know how I could speed up the frame rate?

Comment: I don't know if that's the issue. I don't know what the problem is. You have to identify it first **or** show a video so we can see what you mean. Otherwise, we might waste much time answering something that doesn't actually help you.

Comment: The game is just very slow, since the ship is moving and responds to keypresses and the code I'm using is following a tutorial, and I've looked over it so it doesn't seem like there are any bugs. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kpM_pEV9cY

Comment: The game should resemble something like the one above, however, the ship just moves MUCH slower and so do the aliens

Comment: If it's too slow, then you need a higher `ai_settings.ship_speed_factor`. I know you said it moves "jerky" then but until you have identified what the actual issue is **or** shown a video **of your problem**, there's nothing we can help with. According to your code and description, there's no way to solve your problem **unless**: 1. The ship **doesn't** move each frame, 2. The game lags, 3. There is a bug that messes up time or the ship's position.

Comment: I was able to fix it by running pygame in low resolution so it now moves much faster.

Comment: Okay, then it seems to be a lag issue, which is a bit weird because such a 2D platformer as the one you showed in your youtube link shouldn't lag on a modern computer. Make sure you're loading all your image using [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) and don't load in images or sounds every frame. Also make sure you're not calling any sleep functions like `pygame.time.sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the shop movement is only happening when the keypress UP/DOWN event is received.  Whereas (expressed in the comments) you desire continual movement by holding in the key.

In your case, remove the event-based key handling, and instead look at the function `pygame.key.get_pressed()` which returns a dictionary of the state of every key.

This can be used for continual movement, because it is updated independently of the events.

```
# Start the main loop for the game.
while True:
    gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets) # still need this for exit

    # continuous movement
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        ship.moving_left  = True
        ship.moving_right = False    
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        ship.moving_left  = False
        ship.moving_right = True   

    # update ship position 
    ship.update()
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)
```

And modify the event-handling code to *not* handle the left/right events.

```
def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    #if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    #    ship.moving_right = True
    #elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
    #    ship.moving_left = True
    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to key releases."""
    #if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    #    ship.moving_right = False
    #elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
    #    ship.moving_left = False
    pass
```